# How to show the host/configured/default ssh "configuration"?

Tags: ssh, configuration, defaults

According to my `ssh_config` file...

> Configuration data is parsed as follows:
>
> 1. command line options
> 2. user-specific file
> 3. system-wide file

With that said, (and yes, I know, I *could* scour `man ssh_config` AND `man ssh`, and (hope) for documented defaults).. how can I "print out" the active configuration, for ALL current settings. For example, something like...

`ssh -o Tunnel=ethernet servername -p 2210 --print-config`

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.0
 Command Line Options
   Port 2210
   Host servername
 Command Line Configurations
   Tunnel Ethernet
 Config File
   ...
 SSH Defaults
   ...
   AddressFamily any (???)
   BatchMode no
   ...
```

This would let you know explicitly exactly what is set, and why. I called out `AddressFamily` specifically, as it is a perfect example of a configuration option with **NO documented default value**.   From `man ssh_config`...

> Specifies which address family to use when connecting.  Valid arguments are `any`, `inet` (use IPv4 only), or `inet6` (use IPv6 only).

Ugh! Thanks for any *constructive* suggestions (not just a bunch of `RTFM`'s).

Comment: refer to this [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/390488/verify-sshd-configuration). `sshd` uses the config files to override its internal defaults, that are shown in the stock config files after fresh install

Comment: @gwillie Note: `ssh_config` != `sshd_config`.

Comment: what does it matter, there's no way to do it, I wrote a script when I had to do it, just make sure you parse the files in the right order

Comment: On Mac OS X, only a small subset of the many available options are mentioned in the "stock" config files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is `-G` option in recent openssh, which behaves in similar way as `-T` on server side.

> -G      Causes ssh to print its configuration after evaluating Host and Match blocks and exit.

By calling `ssh -G host` you will get options used for connecting to specific host, which can be helpful for debugging conditional matches in `ssh_config`.

Also setting more verbose log level (`-vvv`) can help with debugging config parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -G remotehost
```

But that prints out all the config, also default ones (~100 lines). Sometimes you just want to check the difference to the default config (when you have some special rules for your host), in this case:

```
comm -13 <(ssh -G non-existing-host | sort) <(ssh -G remotehost | sort)
```

This command compares the config for the `non-existing-host` and for the `remotehost`. If the `non-existing-host` is really something what is not in your config (very likely) then the first `ssh -G...` command gives back the default config.

And here is a `bash` function for the same (takes one parameter the remote `hostname`):

```
ssh-config-diff() {
    local remotehost=$1
    if ! [ "$remotehost" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: hostname required" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    comm -13 <(ssh-config non-existing-host | sort) <(ssh-config $remotehost | sort)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only potential downside of `-G` is that it dumps the entire set of variables for a given target host, which is useful for scripting but can be a little messy to visually sort through.

I kludged together a quick-and-dirty AWK script to meet my needs; give it a fragment of a name found on a `Host` line, and it will print the configuration block as found in the `.ssh/config` file.  Keep in mind that (1) a Host line can have multiple entries on it, and (2) this does assume that configuration lines will be indented for each Host block.  Also, the script does *not* print out any global options specified in the config file, because I didn't want those.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
#
# Given a ~/.ssh/config file that looks like
#
#    SettingOne foo
#    SettingTwo bar
#
#    Host hostX hostY
#      SettingBlah yes
#      SettingBlurg no
#
#    Host hostZ
#      SettingBlurg no
#
# then "print_ssh_block hostY" will print out the corresponding Setting block,
# which is considerably easier for a human to read than the output of
# "ssh -G hostY".

BEGIN {
    if (ARGC != 2) {
        print "Usage:  print_ssh_block host_fragment"
        exit 1
    }

    # ARGV[0] is the script file itself
    # ARGV[1] is the string fragment to later match in Host lines; we don't
    # want to actually process it as a filename...
    hostfrag = ARGV[1]
    # ...so we replace it with the filename of SSH's config, which we DO want
    # to process with patterns.
    ARGV[1] = ENVIRON["HOME"] "/.ssh/config"
    ARGC = 2
    inHostBlock = 0
}

/#/ { next }

/^[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt] / {
    # skip $1, since that's "Host"
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        # $i is the individual host; if it matches the script argument,
        # set or clear the flag appropriately
        inHostBlock = ($i ~ hostfrag) ? 1 : 0
        if (inHostBlock) break
    }
}

# When not in a matching host block, skip the indented lines.
inHostBlock == 0 && /^[[:space:]]/ { next  }

# When inside a matching host block, clear the flag as soon as we reach an
# empty line.
inHostBlock == 1 && /^$/  { inHostBlock = 0 }

# When inside a matching host block, print every line we encounter.
inHostBlock == 1          { print }
```

There are approximately infinite improvements that could be made to this.  True AWK masters can probably write it in about five total lines.